# Как найти PatchCodeGUID с PowerShell?

Tags: com, powershell, vbscript

Для того чтобы найти PatchCodeGUID я использую скрипт:

```
$vbsCode = @"
Set msi = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set patchlist = msi.Patches("{786970C5-E6F6-4A41-B238-AE25D4B91EEA}")
For Each p In patchlist
    WScript.Echo p
Next
"@

$VBSFile = "$env:TEMP\temp.vbs"

$vbsCode | out-file -FilePath $VBSFile
$PatchList = cscript.exe $VBSFile | Where-Object {$_ -match "^{" }
$VBSFile | Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$PatchList
```

Можно ли достичь того же результата используя только PowerShell?

P.S.{786970C5-E6F6-4A41-B238-AE25D4B91EEA} это RTMProductCodeGuid  агента SCOM.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть на этот модуль: https://psmsi.codeplex.com/ . Насколько я понимаю, стандартный com-object "WindowsInstaller.Installer", импортируемый в PS не обладает нужными методами...

Answer (score 1):

```
PS D:\> $msi = New-Object -ComObject 'WindowsInstaller.Installer'
$msi.Patches("{90150000-002A-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}") # office 2013 std

{16F64A9D-6561-4378-98F2-BD2095B78511}
{2A7695E2-F9CD-4392-8458-33F834477076}
```

Win7x64, PS5.0